# Decoding base64 encoded xml message returned from an SQL record in Biztalk

Tags: sql, xml, base64, decode, biztalk

I am receiving a document in Biztalk, which contain some base64 encoded content inside an xml tag.

What I need, is to decode this content (which is a seperate XML document) and insert it into an  in an envelope schema, to then be processed further.

The structure of the received document is like so:

```
    <Polling xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Polling/">
        <PolledData>
            <DataSet xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
                <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                    <xs:element msdata:IsDataSet="true" name="NewDataSet">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="NewTable">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="hostUTC" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="msgType" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="acknowledgment" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sendLog" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="msgFormat" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="msgbody" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
                                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="fromID" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="toID" type="xs:string"/>
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:schema>
                <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                        <NewTable>
                            <ID>123</ID>
                            <hostUTC>2018-11-08T14:53:24.11Z</hostUTC>
                            <msgType>INVOIC</msgType>
                            <msgFormat>Edifact</msgFormat>
                            <msgbody>base64encodedmessage...</msgbody>
                            <fromID>DKT:28504861</fromID>
                            <toID>KMDoioUBL</toID>
                        </NewTable>
                    </NewDataSet>
                </diffgr:diffgram>
            </DataSet>
        </PolledData>
    </Polling>
```

The base64 encoded content is located inside the  tag.
I've already created the envelope schema, which has the following structure:

[image]

The message is received using a WCF-SQL adapter on a receive location. Currently no pipeline has been set up to process the message. In the 'Messages' tab of the adapter configuration it seems there is an option for base64 encoding, though I am not sure what this does or how it works exactly. When using the body setting here I get returned the above XML.

[image]

I'm not sure if this can be done without writing any code. 
Reading [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/12ef0170-e8be-4771-9191-845f7a3ab142/how-should-i-decode-base64-encoded-xml-node-to-a-file-?forum=biztalkgeneral) post on the subject, it seems that I need to write a custom pipeline component to handle the decoding. But first I would need to extract the content of the specific XML node.

I'm unsure how to approach this problem. I'd like to avoid using orchestrations if at all possible. Can this be done in standard Biztalk, or will I need to create custom functionality to handle this process?

Edit: XPath attempts

```
/Polling/PolledData[1]/*[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data' and local-name()='DataSet'][1]/*[namespace-uri()='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1' and local-name()='diffgram'][1]/*[namespace-uri()='' and local-name()='NewDataSet'][1]/*[namespace-uri()='' and local-name()='NewTable'][1]/*[namespace-uri()='' and local-name()='msgbody'][1]

/*[local-name()='Polling']/*[local-name()='PolledData']/*[local-name()='DataSet']/*[local-name()='diffgram']/*[local-name()='NewDataSet']/*[local-name()='NewTable']/*[local-name()='msgbody']

/Polling/PolledData/DataSet/diffgr:diffgram/NewDataSet/NewTable/msgbody

//*[msgbody]/text()
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Path option?  Did it not work?

Comment: I have, I receive the following error message: "System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find match for inbound body path expression". I've used the local-name xPath convention, which MS recommends.

Comment: Well...that sounds like an xPath bug still.  IIRC, you don't need the full path, try using //*[the element].

Comment: Trying this I get a different error: "System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the child value". I've tried with both base64 and String as node encoding.

Comment: Maybe add /body() to the xpath…???

Comment: The other option would be to have a map that links to the node you need to a scripting functoid that calls a helper class to decode the contents

Comment: I think you should append /text() to your xpath. For the body path expression property, only the XPath expressions suitable for forward-only processing of XML are supported. For more information about the XPath expressions available for this property, see "The Best of Both Worlds: Combining XPath with the XmlReader" at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=75701.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using both body() and text(), but I receive an "Invalid expression" error when using body() and the same error when using text(). I think the problem lies in the use of namespace xmlns:diffgr in the diffgram tag. When I copied the xPath from Node++ it did not take this into account. I've edited my post with the xPath attempts I've tried to input.